# Combining Java + bluetooth + arduino

Tags: java, bluetooth, network-programming, arduino, wireless

Today i came up with an idea to controle a arduino board or any other micro controller wirelessly using a java program. Im somewhat of an intermediate java programmer, meaning i can make basic applications. I know next to nothing about arduino, or the programming of microcontrollers in general, and i dont want to start to learn until i know i can link java with arduino, meaning running a program on the computer that, lets say, turn on a led. Ive done some research, and thats where i got the bluetooth from, but it seemed like the only videos were in spanish, and not much documentation about it, as far as i can see. I was just wondering how easy is it to link these two, is it possible, any links to tutorials of sorts, thanks. P.S. it doesn't have to be arduino, im just familier with that name, im just interested in controlling something physical through a java app, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

If you can program in java you will find arduino fairly easy but here is a arduino based tutorial with all the code your need:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Tutorial01#.UxClcvl_tFs

A majority of bluetooth modules will spit out serial data and this simply interacts with the RX/Tx (receive/transmit) inputs of the arduino. They are usually configured to standard board rates mainly 9600 to start.

All you have to do is spit a string out via bluetooth, an java based bluetooth example is below but you can also find bluetooth modules for PC that interact and install as a CDC (serial port).

[Sending a string via bluetooth from a PC as client to a mobile as server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343369/sending-a-string-via-bluetooth-from-a-pc-as-client-to-a-mobile-as-server).

Serial ports are a little easyier :)
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/COM-Port.htm

Cheers,
Chris