# Emulate a Bluetooth Device from PC

Tags: bluetooth, emulation, wireless

I wonder whether it is possible to emulate a specific bluetooth device like a Remote Controller for a TV or another device with my PC. I'd be okay with installing an additional hardware device for my computer (e. g. a BlueTooth PCIe card).

I imagined something like "recording" all single commands of my original remote controller using my Bluetooth card and afterwards use these recorded commands to turn on my TV for example.

Is something like this possible (with additional hardware maybe)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course this is possible. Bluetooth is just a protocol and you can impliment it in your custom software to emulate all kinds of devices. If you need to emulate simple devices like keyboard or mouse, there are many ready solutions like [this](http://www.acrosscenter.com/).

But if you have non standard device, there won't be any ready solutions and you will have to implement it yourself. What can help you:

1. If you have some kind of controller for PC and you want to emulate device with unknown protocol, you can use [WireShark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Bluetooth) or other sniffer to understand what's going on.
2. There is an emulator called [BT-Sim](http://btsim.sourceforge.net/btsim_faq.html), but it is so poorly documented that I can't even guess what it does.
3. You can can take as example different android software like described in answers to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/can-i-emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-my-android-device).
4. You can check different program samples for PC like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343369/sending-a-string-via-bluetooth-from-a-pc-as-client-to-a-mobile-as-server).

For hardware you need only simple Bluetooth dongle. However, if you want to spy on some BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices, you can buy hardware sniffer like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2269).

Answer (score 1):

(At least in Windows 10) Microsoft Store has an application called "Bluetooth LE Explorer" which is able to simulate different kind of Bluetooth GATT profiles as a peripheral.