# Send an object from a java application to an Android application via Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need to send an object from a java application that runs on my laptop to an Android device via Bluetooth. The class is the following:

```
public class Contact {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.id = ++counter;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what library or API to use in order to send data. I think that, first, I have to pair both devices, but I have no idea how to do it neither. After pairing I think that I should have a listener in my Android application that is executed when data has been received, shouldn't I?

I hope you can help me because I totally stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data from a laptop with a running java application to an android device check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343369/sending-a-string-via-bluetooth-from-a-pc-as-client-to-a-mobile-as-server) please. Also, I would recommend use a backend framework to share data between an android app through a web service.

Comment: Thank you @Alberto. I will strongly consider using web services instead of this method because painfully I haven't been able to solve using Bluetooth.